# How can I stop a Thread with jamed stream.Read()? About multithreading

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

My design can be descripted as :
There are missions,Let's call it a mission queue;
I dequeue a mission create a background Thread, read data from internet, and wait until it done; add this thread to my pool.
If there is something wrong, like an exception, I re-enqueue this mission back to the queue for the next worker.

And when I want to Pause or stop all the running **literally IMMEDIATELY and I don't care what happened in the Thread**, like this:

> ```
>         lock (DownloadThreadPool)
>         {
>             for (int i = DownloadThreadPool.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
>             {
>                 if (DownloadThreadPool[i].IsAlive)
>                 {
>                     DownloadThreadPool[i].Abort();
>                     DownloadThreadPool.RemoveAt(i);
>                 }
>             }
>         }
> ```

In my thread, I use such to handle the immediate Abort:

> ```
>            Thread t= new Thread (()=>{
>                     try{
>                        stream.read();
>                     }
>
>                     catch (IOException ioe)
>                     {
>                         lock (UnfinishedVolume)
>                         {
>                             UnfinishedVolume.Enqueue(index);
>                         }
>                         lock (locker)
>                         {
>                             FinishedBytes -= AcceptedBytes[index];
>                             AcceptedBytes[index] = 0;
>                         }
>                     }
>                     catch (ThreadAbortException)
>                     {
>                         lock (DownloadingVolume)
>                         {
>                             lock (UnfinishedVolume)
>                             {
>                                 UnfinishedVolume.Enqueue(index);
>                             }
>                             lock (locker)
>                             {
>                                 FinishedBytes -= AcceptedBytes[index];
>                                 AcceptedBytes[index] = 0;
>                             }
>                         }
>                     }
>   }{isbackground=true}
> ```
>
> //add the thread to pool and run it.

however, I found it can't catch ThreadAbortException Sometimes, so seems the thread doesn't end immediately...for instance ,in this case, When I limit the net speed to 1kb/s in the router.

So does anyone have better idea, that can prove both immediacy and effectiveness?
Many people discourage the usage of Thread.Abort(), But, I really dont know a better way to ensure immediacy. Imagine, When you hit "close the file", sometimes I really don't care what will happpened next, I just want it disappear at once.

When writing here, I came with that I am always wondering, If microsoft NEVER provide a way safe enough to terminate a thread like you terminating an application in Taskmgr or not?

Comment: Have you tried the `Thread.Interrupt()` instead of `Thread.Abort()`? The effect of `Interrupt` is delayed until the target thread is blocked, so it may not be as instantaneous, but it is less dangerous than `Abort`.

Comment: There *is* no safe way to terminate a thread -- this is exactly why `Thread.Abort` is discouraged. `TerminateThread`, the unmanaged function doing this, is no safer. Terminating an entire process is safe because the OS can clean up all resources belonging to the process, but when you terminate a thread any number of resources, including memory and locks, can end up in a corrupted state that makes the entire process behave unreliably, because there is no concept of thread ownership. There *are* safe ways to interrupt I/O (`CancelIo`/`CancelSynchronousIo`), but not for managed code.

Comment: The safe way to do thread termination include 1) cooperative cancellation, including `CancellationToken`, and 2) not at all -- forget about the thread and leave it running, ignoring any results. To cancel IO, the only approach available is to close the original stream/socket/whatnot; this cancels pending I/O operations (of course at the expense of having to redo everything).